# file and memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++, file, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#define READ_
#ifndef READ_
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class read {
    ifstream file("matrices.bin", ios::bin | ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        streampos size = file.tellg();
        char* matrix_Name = new char[4];
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read(matrix_Name, 4);
        file.close();
        return file;
    }
};
#include "read.h"
int txt_file() {
    string name;
    ofstream file1;
    file1.open("results.txt");
    file1 << "original tetx";
    file1 << &file;
    int* mat = new(nothrow) int[4];
    if (mat != nullptr) {
        int min = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) {
                if (arr[j].name < arr[min].name)
                    min = j;
            }
            read temp = arr[min];
            arr[min] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
        int j;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            arr[k] = mat[j];
        }

        ofstream file(wfile);

        if (file.is_open()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                file << "NAME: " << arr[i].name << endl;
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].rows; ++j) {
                    file << "ADRESS OF ROW " << j << ": " << &arr[i].elements[j][0] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
        return arr[k];
    }
    int main() {
        int* s = txt_file();
        int a = *((int*)s);
        if (mat != nullptr) {
            delete[] mat;
        }
        txt_file();
    }
#endif
```

A binary file named "matrices.bin" contains a list of 4 matrices (two-dimensional arrays). Each matrix
in the file is codified in the following format:

- its alphanumerical name, as a string
- its number of rows, as a 32-bit unsigned integer
- its number of columns, as a 32-bit unsigned integer
- all its elements, as 32-bit signed integers

The number of matrices in the file will always be 4.

reads the file "matrices.bin" and stores each matrix in memory, along with their names and
sizes

- creates a text file named "results.txt" to write the following information for each matrix:

  - name of the matrix
  - memory address of each row of the matrix

In the file "results.txt", the matrices should be stored in alphabetical order based on their name.

Assume you have enough resources in your system to store the content of the file "matrices.bin" in
RAM – this means, you can store the whole file at once and you don’t have to use nothrow or exception
handling to verify if the allocation was successful.

Requirements: you should divide the problem into functions and you should not use global variables.

Hint: the string class provides overloads for the comparison operators.

I wrote in c++

My main function code can be wrong I am not sure and What my mistake about code is I could not find.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `class read {` you can't put arbitrary code outside a function.

Comment: `char* matrix_Name = new char[4];` will hold a null terminated c-string of up to 3 total characters. This does not hold 4 file names.

Comment: `int txt_file() {` your function is declared to return 1 single integer.

Comment: `mat` is a variable local to the `txt_file()` function it does not exist in `main()`

Comment: okey thank you I will try again

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the order of your define and ifdef:

```
#define READ_
#ifndef READ_
```

Shall be

```
#ifndef READ_
#define READ_
```

At least I'd begin with that.